# WIX ServiceControl Condition

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.5

I have a property that is set to 1 if the database feature is being installed:

```
<Property Id="DBFLAG" Value="0" />
<CustomAction Id="DbCheck" Return="check" Execute="immediate" Property="DBFLAG" Value="1" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="DbCheck" After="CostFinalize"><![CDATA[&ft_db=3]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

In another feature I check this DBFLAG to see if it is 0 or 1 and based upon this I want to start a service immediately or not:

```
<Component Id="cmp_Svc" Guid="99481212-F2E0-4B6E-934D-0994815C31ED">
            <File Id="FILE01" Source="$(var.Service.TargetDir)\Service.exe" KeyPath="yes" />

            <ServiceInstall Id="Svc" Name="My Service" Type="ownProcess" Account="[WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSYSTEM]" Description="My Service." DisplayName="My Service" ErrorControl="normal" Interactive="no" Start="auto" Vital="no" />
</Component>
<Component Id="cmp_SvcC_Start" Guid="2ED5DBC7-BD42-4D46-AB18-E82DB0E317AD">
            <Condition>DBFLAG=1</Condition>
            <ServiceControl Id="SvcC_Start" Name="My Service"  Remove="uninstall" Stop="both" Wait="yes" Start="install" />
</Component>

<Component Id="cmp_SvcC" Guid="5769A35B-FD61-45D4-8113-40FB762B79C6">
            <Condition>DBFLAG=0</Condition>
            <ServiceControl Id="SvcC" Name="My Service"  Remove="uninstall" Stop="both" Wait="yes" />
</Component>
```

However, it always runs the cmp_SvcC instead of the cmp_SvcC_Start service if the database feature is installed.  I have checked the logs and can see that the DBFLAG is set to 1 before the cmp_SvcC and cmp_SvcC_Start are run but still the cmp_SvcC is run even though the condition is only when DBFLAG=0.

If I change the initial value of the DBFLAG to 1 then the cmp_SvcC_Start gets run.

Has anyone any idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work this way. You cannot condition a component with a feature action, even if your are doing it indirectly through a property.

The correct approach is to share your component between all features which affect its installation. This is done through [FeatureComponents table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368579%28VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4).

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit?  I'm new to wix and am not quite sure what you mean.  Do I add <ComponentRef> for the cmp_SvcC and cmp_SvcC_Start to the db feature?

Comment: WiX doesn't support editing FeatureComponents table. A solution is to modify the generated MSI manually with Orca: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(VS.85).aspx . Another solution is to find a setup authoring tool which allows you to modify this table.

Comment: Cheers, after knowing this I've had to start them from code now as the build process needs to be automated and can't go editing the msi afterwards...

Comment: @Cosmin, that's not true: WiX supports the FeatureComponents table with Component/ComponentRef/ComponentGroupRef under Feature/FeatureRef.

@knappster, see http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/04/09/feature-states-in-component-conditions/ and http://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/05/30/feature-conditions-and-ui/ for why your original technique won't work.

Comment: @BobArnson we cannot update FeatureComponents table .reason is both columns are primary keys. we need to only delete and create new row ref:http://www.faqshop.com/scripting/default.htm?http://www.faqshop.com/scripting/msi/sql%20queries%20win%20inst.htm

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do is have a condition on the StartServices custom action itself. Like this:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<StartServices Sequence="5900">
    <![CDATA[VersionNT AND DBFLAG="1"]]>
</StartServices>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

In order to get a clue what Sequence number you want to use, open your msi with Orca, look at the InstallExecuteSequence table and sort the table after Sequence number.

Comment: Also note that you don't have to set the `Sequence` number - MSI/WIX will set one by default, which is usually 5900.